# Zend Frame Work Data base Configuration and connection

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have installed zend server for zend framework.I didnt install xampp or wampp.Which software i have to install for database configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend uses PDO driver to connect to databse.

Any database that has PDO driver will do. You can look at [list of drivers on php.net site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php). Also here is [some documentation from Zend on databases and PDO drivers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html).